# Set python variables to operators?

Tags: python, math

## Python, Operators set to variables?

I am making a calculator and I want the user to be able to enter words like add to `+`. 
 Is there any way to set python variables to operands. e.g.

```
operands = {
    "add": +
}
```

etc.

Is there any way to do this  **without modules**. But if not possible is there a module?

Comment: ... you what now ?

Comment: First: no. Second: the word is "operator". "Operand" is something else. Third: use a function.

Comment: Sorry, your right. What sort of function do you propose?

Comment: A function that just adds its arguments together with `+`.

Comment: One such function is provided in the `operator` module, or you could write your own in one line.

Comment: you probably want something like `{'+': operator.add}`.

Comment: OK, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the alternative using libraries (a standard one so no reason not to)

```
import operator as op

d = dict([
    ('^', op.pow),
    ('**', op.pow),
    ('*', op.mul),
    ('/', op.truediv),
    ('//', op.floordiv),
    ('+', op.add),
    ('-', op.sub)
    ])

d['*'](2,3)
```

Returns: `6`

Comment: `operator.pow` is a better match for Python's `**` operator than `math.pow`. (It produces integer outputs from integer inputs, for one thing.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use two-argument functions, such as lambdas.

```
ops = {
    "add": lambda a, b: a + b,
    "sub": lambda a, b: a - b,
    "mul": lambda a, b: a * b,
    "div": lambda a, b: a + b,
    "pow": lambda a, b: a ** b
    # and so on
}

x = 42
y = 13
op = "add"

print(ops[op](x, y))     # 55
```

The module `operator` includes predefined functions like this for all of Python's built-in operators.

Comment: This is great, thanks @kindall. I think I will use this.

Comment: I liket this answer but I never understood why people refuse to use standard libraries... still puzzles me.